# Misunderstanding of class of returned instance from generic method of class called from subclass instance in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Example:

```
interface S {}

interface SS extends S {}

abstract class A<T extends S> {
    T get() {…}
}

abstract class B<BT extends SS> extends A<BT> {}
```

Why does `((B)someInstanceOfB).get()` return an object of type `S` (and we should cast it to `SS` manually), when the compiler could determine that returned object is at least of type `SS`?

Why doesn't the compiler make implicit class cast to have clearer code? The code is of version 1.5+ and this is not secret for compiler. (Solved)

*Update:* Why doesn't the compiler compile `B` class as it implicitly has method `BT get() { return super.get(); }` ?

Is this problem solved in Java 1.7+?

Comment: I don't understand the question clearly. But `S` and `SS` are interfaces here.

Comment: @silverback revised question. What's a problem with interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By casting to `B` you're using [a raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Using a raw type removes **all generic information** from the object, no matter where it is.

That means that for the raw type `B` the `get` method *looks like* it is returning a `S` (because that's the erasure (i.e. the actual type used at runtime) of the type parameter `T`).

To avoid this, **never use raw types**! They are meant exclusively for backwards compatibility and interaction with legacy code.

Cast to `B<? extends SS>` instead.

And no: this problem will probably never be "solved" in any future version of Java, as it's non-existing when you use generics correctly.

Regarding Update: no, `B` does **not** have a method `BT get()`. It has a method `T get()` where `T` is bound to the type parameter `BT` which has a lower bound `SS`. But since all generic type information is discarded when you use a raw type, `T` will **still** fall back to the original erasure, which is `S`.

The *rule* is quite simple and basically says "when you use a raw type it acts as if the class has no generics at all". The implications, however, are not always obvious, as in this case.

Comment: I get you. It is made for backward compatibility of compiled classes: to have possibility to use compiled code of new versions with obsolete code and compilers.

Comment: Some thoughts about question update. It was a rhetorical question. I understand that, till compiler logic proposed by me doesn't implemented (defined by standard) in 1.5v compiler, it will be never implemented. As for me, cast to `B<? extends SS>` corrupts aesthetic of code, and I have been preferred some more bytes in compiled class (implicit method proposed by me).

Comment: Well, using `B` corrupts the *logic* of the code. If this is such an important issue for you (and you don't mind all the "raw type" warnings), then you can just add a manual method `BT get()` into your `B` class an achieve the same effect. The logic of how Java handles raw types is *very unlikely* to change significantly, for the reasons I stated. And if *you* prefer a few more bytes, that goal might very well conflict with other goals of *other people* (for example what if the method `get` was added to `A` **after** your class `B` was compiled?).

Comment: Also: if it's a rhetorical question, then why make an edit and even draw my focus to that edit? That makes it look like you want an answer.

Comment: I liked to read your thoughs. And case proposed by you _(“what if the method `get` was added to `A` after your class `B` was compiled?”)_ is really important reason why it is so.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't parameterize your instance of `B`.

Let's say you have the class `C` implementing `SS`:

Then, `new B<C>().get();` would return an object of type `C`.

On the `new B().get();` line, your IDE must have told you *"B is a raw type. References to generic type B should be parameterized."*.

Comment: @Errandir The problem remains the same: using `(B) someInstanceOfB`, you don't parameterize `B`. You have to use `(B<C>) someInstanceOfB`, or `(B<?>) someInstanceOfB` at least (`get` will then return an `Object`).

Comment: There is something wrong in your argumentation. Code chunks `S s = ((B)someInstanceOfB).get()` and `S s = ((A)someInstanceOfA).get()` will work fine.

Comment: We have partially parametrized `A`.